# Gitlab-CI: не запускается build при пуше

Tags: git, администрирование, gitlab

Есть Gitlab 8.1.0pre.
После создания ранеров и добавление их в Gitlab-CI, они никак не реагируют на push в проект. Причём если вручную запустить (нажать кнопку Project > Settings > Services > Gitlab CI > Test setting) то сборка проходит отлично, на последний коммит.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Может, вы пушите в какую-то ветку фичи, а раннеры смотрят исключительно на `master`?

Comment: Нет, специально добавил тестовый проект в котором есть только мастер.

Comment: Нашел другой важный момент, gitlab вообще не отмечает в своей система что бы push event, в вкладке activity. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился сам собой. "gitlab-ctl reconfigure" выдал:

```
STDERR: usermod: user git is currently used by process 1356
```

Собственно вылечилось перезагрузкой. После чего все начало работать в штатном режиме.